# Why does my mesh contort only when I move one side of my rig?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I’m relatively new to blender and I’ve created a character rig attached to my mesh. When I move the left side of the model, everything works normally, but when I move the right side, the mesh folds in on itself.

I used a mirror modifier for the mesh but I’ve removed
it; duplicating the left side of the mesh, and attaching it onto the right side. I have also tried weight painting and merging vertices but none of it works, any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: Hello maybe you need to recalculate the normals (Shift N in Edit mode)? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FlpFPj8I7IjKiehg8g8ktbA1ak_V6BPN/view?usp=drive_link